# Python Falcon and Axios: Unable to allow CORS

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, falcon

I'm having difficulty allowing CORS requests to a Flask server. The client is React using axios. The error on the client is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at <url> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

If I navigate to the url directly in the browser (on a either PC), it loads no problem. But when using axios it breaks.

I have tried the following strategies:

1) Directly append header:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import falcon
import transform
import json
import engine

index = transform.reindex()
app = falcon.API()

class Search:
    def on_get(self, request, response):
        query = request.params['searchText']
        result = engine.search(query, index)

        response.append_header('access-control-allow-origin', '*')
        response.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        response.body = json.dumps(result)

search = Search()
app.add_route('/search', search)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with make_server('', 8003, app) as httpd:
        print('Serving on port 8003...')
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

2) Using falcon_cors globally through middleware:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import falcon
from falcon_cors import CORS    
from flask import jsonify
import transform
import json
import engine


cors = CORS(allow_origins_list=[
    '<client ip>'
    ])

index = transform.reindex()
app = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])


class Search:
    def on_get(self, request, response):
        query = request.params['searchText']
        result = engine.search(query, index)


        response.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        response.body = json.dumps(result)


search = Search()

app.add_route('/search', search)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with make_server('', 8003, app) as httpd:
        print('Serving on port 8003...')
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

1) using falcon-cors locally:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import falcon

from falcon_cors import CORS


from flask import jsonify
import transform

import json
import engine


cors = CORS(allow_origins_list=['*'])

index = transform.reindex()
app = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])

public_cors = CORS(allow_all_origins=True)

class Search:
    cors = public_cors
    def on_get(self, request, response):
        query = request.params['searchText']

        response.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        response.body = json.dumps(result)


search = Search()

app.add_route('/search', search)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with make_server('', 8003, app) as httpd:
        print('Serving on port 8003...')
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

Nothing is working. When I inspect the response in the browser, I can see 'access-control-allow-origin': '*' I read somewhere that axios can't always see all the headers. Has anyone encountered this before? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A possible scenario-

When using a browser, it attaches `withCredentials: true` in your requests if server demands it. But when it comes to Angular or React, you have to explicitly provide `withCredentials: true` in your `httpOptions`.

---

I'd recommend you to use either Falcon or Flask.
The following procedure might be helpful if just using Falcon under gunicorn or waitress-

Get [falcon-cors](https://pypi.org/project/falcon-cors/)

```
from falcon_cors import CORS
```

Have some **whitelisted methods**.

```
# Methods supported by falcon 2.0.0
# 'CONNECT', 'DELETE', 'GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT', 'TRACE'

whitelisted_methods = [
    "GET",
    "PUT",
    "POST",
    "PATCH",
    "OPTIONS" # this is required for preflight request
]
```

Know more on [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Search class as follows

```
class Search:

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        response_obj = {
            "status": "success"
        }
        resp.media = response_obj
```

Have some **whitelisted origins**.

```
whitelisted_origins = [
    "http://localhost:4200",
    "https://<your-site>.com"
]
```

Add cors in your middleware

```
cors = CORS(
    # allow_all_origins=False,
    allow_origins_list=whitelisted_origins,
    # allow_origins_regex=None,
    # allow_credentials_all_origins=True,
    # allow_credentials_origins_list=whitelisted_origins,
    # allow_credentials_origins_regex=None,
    allow_all_headers=True,
    # allow_headers_list=[],
    # allow_headers_regex=None,
    # expose_headers_list=[],
    # allow_all_methods=True,
    allow_methods_list=whitelisted_methods
)

api = falcon.API(middleware=[
    cors.middleware,
    # AuthMiddleware()
    # MultipartMiddleware(),
])
```

Now you can add a route to your class.

```
from src.search import SearchResource
api.add_route('/search', SearchResource())
```

---

For your reference, if there is `withCredentials: true` in the incoming request, make sure you don't miss `allow_credentials_origins_list` set to `whitelisted_origins` in the `cors` above.

OR

If you want to allow credentials then you should not set `allow_all_origins` to `True`. You will have to specify the exact protocol + domain + port in `allow_credentials_origins_list`.